# How can I edit TPL files using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse to develop an eshop using Prestashop.

Since `tpl` files aren't supported by default, I cannot validate my code, there is no syntax highlight or anything.

Is there a plugin or something to do my job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight .tpl syntax in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079399/highlight-tpl-syntax-in-eclipse)

Comment: @Prisoner I think not. Its not about syntax highlighting only (prestashop developing). I think the question is more general and since the other questing does not provide an answer, I would like one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good plugin to handle these kind of template files : [smartypdt](http://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/) .

Comment: This project is outdated (last version is somewhere in 2009..).
Aren't there any active projects to support this? Also, I am using XDebug and not Zend debugger.