# Install SmartyPDT 0.0.9.1 in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I just installed the latest version of Eclipse Kepler which is RC3 (found at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php). I had been using this "smartyPDT" (found at https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/ ) plugin for all previous versions but i cant seem to install this plugin anymore. I get the error

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: Smarty Feature 0.91.0 

 (org.eclipse.php.smarty_feature.feature.group 0.91.0)
 Missing requirement: Smarty Feature 0.91.0 (org.eclipse.php.smarty_feature.feature.group 0.91.0) requires 'org.eclipse.php 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I tried with the old version of smartyPdt which is 0.9.0 and also the 0.9.1. Any idea how to solve this issue or better yet how to get the SmartyPDT to work wih Kepler?

Comment: org.eclipse.php was removed since pdt3.1.2.

Comment: I also got the same issue. Any solutions already?

Comment: @StefanS, I had to copy and paste that folder from an old installation   and it worked but I am not sure if there will be conflicts with newer versions of this  `org.eclipse.php 0.0.0`. Hopefully someone has a better answer

Comment: @shawndreck If the "Group items by category" check-box is checked, uncheck it.Now you should be able to see 1 item in the software list named "Smarty Feature". And click "Next".

Comment: @LazyCatIT after fiddling around with this problem and searching for alternative to eclipse, I found PHPStorm and I'm sold. This is to say I have abandoned this problem and the quest for a solution. Hope it gets resolved though for those who need it! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

### Here's a quick fix -> Just use the juno update site to install a compatible version of PDT with the smarty plugin:

*(1) Start eclipse.*

*(2) Under the help menu, click on install new software.*

*(3) Click Add.*

*(4) Input any name, then http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ in the location field, then press ok.*

*(5) Select the newly added update site from the drop down list, then select Eclipse PDT and install.*

*(6) After eclipse restarts, installing [smartypdt](https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/wiki/InstallSmartyPDT) will work now.*

---

#### *** * * If you've already installed PDT via the Kepler update site: * * ***

1. just go to your eclipse installation,
2. open the features folder,
3. DELETE the entire folder named `org.eclipse.php_3.2.0.201306051924`,
4. Restart eclipse, then follow then install PDT via the juno update site.

[smarty](/questions/tagged/smarty)[eclipse-4.3](/questions/tagged/eclipse-4.3)[kepler](/questions/tagged/kepler)[pdt](/questions/tagged/pdt)[plugins](/questions/tagged/plugins)[features](/questions/tagged/features)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I had PDT installed via Kepler and removed the folder you suggested, but when trying new installation, Eclipse keeps telling me, that PDT is already installed

Answer (score 2):

These steps just worked for me on Eclipse Kepler:

1. Install Juno version of PDT
2. Install Smarty PDT
3. Remove Juno version of PDT
4. Install Kepler version of PDT

You have latest versions of PDT and Smarty plugins.

Comment: I am yet to try this but looks promising. Does this method guarranttee syntax highlighting among other features?

Comment: @shawndreck This method guarantees that you get the latest versions of plugins working, beyond that it's up to a plugin. For the record this smarty plugin is crappy and the reason why there is no version for Kepler is because they stopped developing it. I suppose it's better than nothing.

Comment: I guess you are right, I manage to get it to install but that is just it! No useful functionality provided. Seriously thinking of switching to PHPStorm if there seems to be no hope in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To install Smarty PDT to latest PDT use http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/ update site. Feature is under "Text Editors / Productivity tools" category.

Answer (score 0):

There is hope to solve this issue

One way I have been told to solve this issue is this

1. Download the Smarty PDT
2. Unpack its content.jar to edit the content.xml file inside
3. Delete both lines 36 and 134 containing the org.eclipse.php dependencies listed and save the changes
4. Re-pack (compress) the content.xml into content.jar and re-pack the content.jar into its original location/folder.
5. Install the plugin as usual

I tried this method and the installation worked without any glitch.

Thanks a million to a user `stanisla...@gmail.com` on directing me through all this. Take a look at https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/issues/detail?id=71 for further details on this issue

NB: After installing I dont get any syntax highlighting at all. I cannot even locate any smarty related stuffs in the eclipse preference modal window.

At least there is a progress...

Comment: I've tried on Zend Studio 11, it passes the error message but then totally fails during the installation

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an archived update site compatible with Eclipse Kepler and the latest PDT release.
Find the download and further information at http://www.bar54.de/blog/2013/02/phpeclipse-and-smarty/

Answer (score 0):

For those which want to try the badfish331 answer, it works, but only the unistall process part is wrong.

To unistall your current PDT software, go to "help"=>"about eclipse"=>"installation details" and unistall PDT.

Then install the Juno's PDT, smartyPDT and everything should be working well.

Answer (score 0):

- Click "install new software" under "help" menu
- click "add"

  - give it a name (ie. PDT Extensions)
  - add http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/ in the location field
  - press "ok"
- type in "smarty" in the filter bar.
- click the checkbox and click the "next" button and continue through saying "yes" or "ok".

File Association
- General -> Editors -> File Associations
- "Add" new file association "*.tpl" (for example).

If this is a known file extension for Smarty, it will automatically get associated to the right program and you can just click "ok" at the bottom.